# .NET Core 2.0 Web API Controller routing (POST with optional [FromBody] Parameter) for receiving web hooks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.0

Currently I try to implement a .NET Core 2.0 Web API web hook.

The webhook on the sending server can simply be configured as:

```
"endpoint": "http://localhost:50100/api/Hook"
```

The sending server does two things:

- on startup it sends an empty post to the defined endpoint to check if it is there and which media types are supported
- later on the events are sent as plain json in the post body to the defined endpoint

I implemented a HookController and know I am facing a (for me) strange routing problem.

The controller implementation is as follows:

```
    [Route("api/Hook")]
public class HookController : Controller
{
  protected ILogger<HookController> Logger { get; set; }

  public HookController(ILogger<HookController> logger)
  {
    Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
  }

  [HttpPost]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Consumes("application/json")]
  public IActionResult HookReceiverLookUp()
  {
    Logger.LogInformation("Hook Receiver POST lookup called");
    return Ok();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Consumes("application/json")]
  public IActionResult HookReceiverEvent([FromBody] JObject res)
  {
    if (res == null)
    {
      Logger.LogInformation("Lookup called (most likely because post body was null)");
      return Ok();
    }
    Logger.LogInformation("Hook Receiver event");
    return Ok();
  }

}
```

The problem is simple:

- If I have only the HookReceiverLookUp method the server recognizes a valid endpoint at startup but obviously this method can't receive data
- If I only have the HookReceiverEvent method it could receive json from POST body but it does not get recognized as a valid endpoint (even with [FromBody] JObject res = null)
- If I have both methods the receiving web api won't start with an exception

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

---

So what are the differences between those two methods (web api says none) and how do I combine them into one method (since the server config let's me only define one method)?

---

### My final solution

Based on Lennarts inputs I got a working implementation draft up and running.

```
public class HookController : Controller
{
  protected ILogger<HookController> Logger { get; set; }

  public HookController(ILogger<HookController> logger)
  {
    Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
  }

  //configuration url: http://localhost:[port]/api/Hook/endpoint
  [HttpPost("Endpoint")]
  public IActionResult HookReceiver([FromHeader(Name = "Content-Type")] string type)  //do not bind JObject here
  {

    if (type == null) return HookReceiverLookUp();   //check if it is the initial look up call / ignore body

    //avoiding built in / default model binder and read the body yourself if necessary
    string body;

    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
      body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //optionally convert it to Json if you want to work with json
    JObject obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(body);

    if (obj == null) return Ok(); //what else??

    return HookReceiverEvent(obj);
  }

  private IActionResult HookReceiverLookUp()
  {
    Logger.LogInformation("Hook Receiver POST lookup called");
    return Ok();
  }

  private IActionResult HookReceiverEvent(JObject res)
  {
    Logger.LogInformation("Hook Receiver POST lookup called\r\n" + res.ToString());
    return Ok();
  }

}
```

A big thank you Lennart for your great help and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could define either as a different type, using `[HttpGet]` for `HookReceiverLookUp()` and `[HttpPost]` for `HookReceiverEvent([FromBody] JObject res)`.

**EDIT**

Try something like this then:

```
[Route("api/Hook")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public class HookController : Controller
{
    private ILogger<HookController> Logger { get; set; }

    public HookController(ILogger<HookController> logger)
    {
        Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    return Request.Headers.Any(
            header => header.Key == "HeaderContentType" && header.Value == "application/json")
            ? HookReceiverEvent(Request.GetBody())
            : HookReceiverLookUp();

    private IActionResult HookReceiverLookUp()
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Hook Receiver POST lookup called");
        return Ok();
    }

    private IActionResult HookReceiverEvent(JObject res)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Hook Receiver event");
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Then you also need a class somewhere with extension-methods. Mine looks like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static JObject GetBody(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        string body;
        request.EnableRewind();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        request.Body.Position = 0;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(body);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be easy but does not work since both calls (the events and startup) are sent as POST. If I change the lookup to GET it is not recognized as valid endpoint.

Comment: Have you tried specifying your routes further with  `[HttpPost("endpointname")] `?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean right now. If I would define [HttpPost("lookup"] and [HttpPost("events"] those would lead to two different URLs on the controller which is a problem since I can only define one endpoint url on the server. Have I understood you right?

Comment: Ah yes! I wasn't sure that you couldn't do that. Well then, have you tried `[ActionName("HookReceiverEvent")]` and define them using the same actionname?

Comment: So far I haven't used ActionName and I can't get it to work. If I add the ActionName annotation to both I and then type localhost:50100/enpoint or localhost:50100/api/endpoint or localhost:50100/api/Hook/endpoint I always get 404 as response. Any hint what I a doing wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer. This way you get a general route that passes the object between private actions

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem and gave me the expected behaviour testing it with post man.

Comment: grml, figured out the problem in my real world scenario. Do you know a way to get the method called if one request sends content type application/json and the other sends the post without any content type?

Comment: I updated my answer again, you should check your request-headers and see what content-type is set there. If the API has been called correctly, a content-type header should have been set correctly

Comment: Thank you again. Unfortunatly that does not work. If no content-type is set the hook receiver method isn't reached and the framework returns 415 Unsupported media type before calling the method. To show you what I am trying to implement right now: it is a web hook for minio server https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/5204

Comment: Updated again. You have to disable the standard modelbinder and check depending on headers whether you should fetch the body or not

Comment: I found a solution without modifying/disabling the standard modelbinder. Thanks for your help.